# Running javascript via a crawller to test client-side code

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

We have a javascript snippet that will be embedded in 3rd party sites. I have a list of 100 potential such sites, and I want to test if the snippet really does what I think it does.

In other words: I want to run my javascript on my server, fetch a list of pages and test whether the javascript code works (results to go in some sort of logfile).

- What's an easy way to do this?
- Are Node.js or Selenium the way to go?
- Any pointers to a Hello World program that could give me a quick start here?

Comment: http://seleniumhq.org/ may help

Comment: Thanks @James - I thought of Selenium as well, forgot to write that down in the question. I would have to configure it to work via some proxy that will add my js, right?

Comment: Dunno. You may be able to get selenium runner to add your JS for you. I think your bigger problem is checking if it "works" - cos you have to do some standard tests to see if your code works but you also have to check the site you have inserted it into doesn't break.

Comment: @James - let's say I don't care about breaking the site right now, I just want to get some logs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into Selenium [User Extensions](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html)? I'm not sure if this will do the job for you, but it might help.